# Counting smileys in a List of strings

Tags: java, string, list

I am trying to count the occurrence of smileys in a given `List` of `Strings`.

Smileys are in format of `:` or `;` for eyes, optional nose `-` or `~`, and mouth of `)` or `D`.

```
import java.util .*;

public class SmileFaces {

    public static int countSmileys(List<String> arrow) {

        int countF = 0;
        for (String x : arrow) {
            if (x.charAt(0) == ';' || x.charAt(0) == ':') {
                if (x.charAt(1) == '-' || x.charAt(1) == '~') {
                    if (x.charAt(2) == ')' || x.charAt(2) == 'D') {
                        countF++;

                    } else if (x.charAt(1) == ')' || x.charAt(1) == 'D') {
                        countF++;

                    }

                }

            }
        }
        return countF;
    }
}
```

Comment: Do you have a problem or are you just showing off your code?

Comment: Please provide sample input data, desired results and observed results.

Comment: This will throw an `IndexOutOfBoundsException` if the string size is smaller than 3; you may want to add some validations for that. Also, maybe you should take a look at the `Pattern` class; it would solve the problem more elegantly.

Comment: `countSmileys(Collections.singletonList(""))`

Comment: sorry...its not working......test case.....expected results <1> got result <0>

Comment: @Test
    public void test2() {
        List<String> a = new ArrayList<String>();
        a.add(":)"); a.add("XD"); a.add(":0}"); a.add("x:-"); a.add("):-"); a.add("D:");
        assertEquals(1, SmileFaces.countSmileys(a));
    }

Comment: @JK'sScowling edit your question with the test, desired input and output.

Answer (score 1):

Better to use a regexp expression for this. This small code uses regexp to find all the patterns and report the count:

```
import java.util.regex.Pattern;
import java.util.regex.Matcher;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.Arrays;

// one class needs to have a main() method
public class Test
{

  private static final Pattern pattern = Pattern.compile("[:;][-~]?[)D]");

  // arguments are passed using the text field below this editor
  public static void main(String[] args)
  {

    List<String> arrow = Arrays.asList(":-) ;~D :) ;D", "sdgsfs :-)");

    System.out.println("found: " + countSmileys(arrow));

  }

    public static int countSmileys(List<String> arrow) {

      int count = 0;
      for (String x : arrow) {
          Matcher matcher = pattern.matcher(x);

          while(matcher.find()) {
              count++;
          }            
      }

      return count;
    }

}
```

Comment: I want to upvote, but OP never actually asked a question, so I don't know if this is a valid answer

Comment: hey, thats a nice way...I dont know why I always veer from regex.....thanks

Comment: Almost any string processing is better to do with RegExp. Except for the complex hierarchical structures like JSON or XML or similar.

Comment: thanks.....I'm going to sit down now this evening with regex- recall it, i remember doing it a couple of years back and how it became much much less scary with just a little understanding...thanks for the help...and sorry for not being clear with my question.....ill get the hang of this site soon....been off it too long

Comment: There are a lot of online regexp testing websites. You don’t need java to test them. Search in google for “regexp online”

Answer (score 0):

Best answer is using `regex` expression matching.

But because there are only few smiles you can try:

```
@Test
public void countSmiles() {
    String smiles = ":),:-D,:~D,:~)";

    int count = StringUtils.countMatches(smiles,":)");
    count += StringUtils.countMatches(smiles,":D");
    count += StringUtils.countMatches(smiles,":-)");
    count += StringUtils.countMatches(smiles,":~)");
    count += StringUtils.countMatches(smiles,":-D");
    count += StringUtils.countMatches(smiles,":~D");
    System.out.println("count = " + count);
}
```

Output:

```
count = 4
```

Comment: Might want to mention that this is from Apache Commons Lang